# How to get a user's Google API token without client id and client id secret?

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-api

I'm making an app that requires access to a Google account. At the moment I'm using the long way of having to create a project, create keys, and many intermediary steps that make it too long for the user.

This is the part where the user is authenticated:

```py
google_scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"]

api_service_name = "youtube"
api_version = "v3"
client_secrets_file = "config.json"

# Get credentials and create an API client
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
    client_secrets_file, google_scopes)
credentials = flow.run_console()
youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
    api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)
```

I just want it to be done without a config file with the keys. Just a link that requires the user to login, and then the tokens are returned.